# Generate *all* coprime tuples

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes

Given integers `k` and `n`, generate a sequence of `n` unique *k-tuples* of pairwise coprime integers. *Every* such tuple must occur once eventually, that is, for any existing k-tuple of pairwise coprime integers, some `n` will eventually generate it.

The output may be printed or evaluated in any list/tuple-like form.

#### Definitions

- Two numbers `a` and `b` are **coprime** if `gcd(a, b) = 1`, i.e. they share no common divisor other than 1.
- A tuple of `k` numbers `(a1, a2, ..., ak)` is **pairwise coprime** if every pair of numbers in the tuple is coprime.

#### Examples

```
 k =  1, n =  5 -> [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
 k =  2, n =  7 -> [[2,1],[3,1],[3,2],[4,1],[4,3],[5,1],[5,2]]
 k =  3, n = 10 -> [[3,2,1],[4,3,1],[5,2,1],[5,3,1],[5,3,2],[5,4,1],[5,4,3],[6,5,1],[7,2,1],[7,3,1]]
 k =  4, n =  2 -> [[5,3,2,1],[5,4,3,1]]
 k =  5, n =  0 -> []
```

#### Notes

- Standard code golf rules, shortest code wins.
- `k` is assumed to be positive, and `n` non-negative.
- The numbers within each tuple must be positive, distinct, and may appear in any order.
- Uniqueness is up to ordering: e.g. `(1,2,3)` is the same as `(1,3,2)`.
- Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Is "print [1, 1, ...[k-1 ones]..., x] for x in range from 1 to n" valid?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Lol I see, "*every* tuple of k pairwise coprime integers is seen exactly once", but I'll clarify.

Comment: I think your comment reduced clarity. Do we have to write a program that can output *all* possible tuples, or it simply has to produce no repetitions?

Comment: "such that as n grows large..." This confused me too.  The input is a fixed n and k -- how are we talking about what happens when n grows large?  Indeed, you might say I am a _bit_ confused.

Comment: @Jonah Removed the mathy stuff, tried making it more concrete. Thank you!

Comment: I believe `k = 0` should be excluded from the input range, as there is only *one* possible k-tuple `[]`.

Comment: @Bubbler good point!

Comment: Does the output have to be the sequence of the first n tuples that satisfy the condition, or any n tuples that satisfy the condition? The second sentence is very confusing to me.

Comment: I think maybe the first sentence is saying that it's the "first n tuples", but the order can be specified by the submission - as long as it can guarantee that a given tuple will eventually appear for some finite n?

Comment: Suggested test case: k=4, n=2 (or any other with k>n>0).

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

I think it has been 389 days since I last posted something here haha. There is definitely some golfing potential left in this program.

#### Code

Uses the [**05AB1E**-encoding](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md).

```
∞æ¹ùʒPy.¿Q}²£
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//@KInsOmwrnDucqSUHkuwr9RfcKywqP//zMKMTA)

#### Explanation

It is worth noting that for two numbers \$n, m \in \mathbb{Z}^+\$ that:

$$
\tag{1} \label{1}
\gcd(n, m) \cdot \text{lcm}(n, m) = n \cdot m
$$

This means that for two numbers \$n, m \in \mathbb{Z}^+\$ where the \$\gcd(n, m) = 1\$, we can conclude that the \$\text{lcm}(n, m) = n \cdot m\$.

Furthermore, the \$\gcd\$ function is a multiplicative function, which means that if \$n_1\$ and \$n_2\$ are relatively prime, then:

$$
\gcd(n_1 \cdot n_2, m) = \gcd(n_1, m) \cdot \gcd(n_2, m)
$$

From this, we obtain the fact that:

$$
\tag{2} \label{2}
\gcd(a, bc) = 1 \iff \gcd(a, b) = 1 \wedge \gcd(a, c) = 1
$$

Let us denote a \$k\$-tuple of positive integers as \$S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k\}\$. A set \$S\$ is pairwise coprime, if and only if:

$$
\tag{3} \label{3}
\forall a, b \in S \wedge a \not = b \rightarrow \gcd(a, b) = 1
$$

Using Equations \$\eqref{1}, \eqref{2}\$ and \$\eqref{3}\$, we can conclude that a set \$S = \{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k\}\$ is pairwise coprime, if and only if:

$$
\text{lcm}(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_k) = \prod_{x \in S} x
$$

#### Code Explanation

```
∞æ¹ùʒPy.¿Q}²£

∞æ              # Powerset of the infinite list [1, ..., ∞].
  ¹ù            # Keep only lists of length k.
    ʒ     }     # Filter. Keep lists where the
     P          #   product of the list
         Q      #   is equal to
      y.¿       #   the least common multiple of the list
           ²£   # Retrieve the first n elements.
```

Comment: Hey, Adnan, it's been long!

Comment: Hey @LuisMendo, it has been a long time indeed! Good to see you ;).

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: Why doesn't `ù` and `£` take existing items on the stack?

Comment: @Λ̸̸  – Mostly shitty programming when I developed the language.

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
↑fËoε⌋`ṖN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9odXNr///ihpFmw4tvzrXijItg4bmWTv///zP/MTA)

### Explanation

A straightforward solution, not the most exciting.

```
↑fËoε⌋`ṖN  Implicit inputs, say k=3, n=2.
        N  Natural numbers: [1,2,3,4,..
      `Ṗ   All k-element subsets: [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[1,3,4],..
           ` flips the arguments of Ṗ since it expects the number first.
 f         Keep those that satisfy this:
  Ë          All pairs x,y (not necessarily adjacent) satisfy this:
     ⌋         their gcd
   oε          is at most 1.
           Result is all pairwise coprime subsets: [[1,2,3],[1,3,4],..
↑          Take the first n: [[1,2,3],[1,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 106 bytes

```
(s=Range[#2#];If[#==1,List/@s,SortBy[Select[s~(S=Subsets)~{#},Union[GCD@@@#~S~{2}]=={1}&],Last][[;;#2]]])&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcfBCsIgGADge08RCGODH5rW6DAEqSCCHSLpJP/Bhi2hOZh2iDFf3W6x7/b1OrxMr4Ntdep4yj2/adcZRRjB@vJUhHMKjfVhIzzIYQyHr5LmbdqgfMwll5@HN8EXcSIz3J0dnDofT0IIEmWc2IycT3TOEBrtAypV14QhYpGl62hdWItOUahw9R@D/WJboOWiO2CLVVBiSj8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
‘×ÆNœcŒcg/€$ÐṂḣ⁸
```

A dyadic Link accepting `n` on the left and `k` on the right.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9qZWxsef//4oCYw5fDhk7Fk2PFkmNnL@KCrCTDkOG5guG4o@KBuP/Dp8WS4bmY//8w/zQ)**

There must be a better way than this inefficient monstrosity! It'll time out for quite small inputs since it inspects all k-tuples of the natural numbers up to the `(n+1)*k`-th prime! (The `+1` is only needed to handle `n=0`.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 153 bytes

```python
lambda n,k,R=range:[[*t,r]for r in R(n+k+2)for t in combinations(R(1,r),k-1)if all(sum(x%i<1for x in[*t,r])<2for i in R(2,r))][:n]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BDoIwEADvvKIXkxZqIuiJwCe4IoeiVDe0W7KsCb6@0pB4nWRmli@/A16jbe/RGT8@jUA9664lg6@p7vucNQ02kCABKDqJxVxUKgFO4BH8CGgYAq6yk6UmpedzqcAK45xcP15uJ2jKJGy7cPRUUyUAR7LaJTX0NQ6ZpeAF8EQcglsF@CUQ5/G/s7K66JuqM7EQIEtW8Qc)

A function that takes `n, k` as arguments and returns out the list of `n` co-prime k-tuples.

The tuple are generated with increasing maximum, so it's guaranteed that every co-prime tuple will eventually be printed as `n` increases.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 143 bytes

Takes input as `(k)(n)`.

```javascript
(k,x=0)=>F=n=>n?(g=a=>x>>i?x>>i++&1?a.some(x=>(C=(a,b)=>b?C(b,a%b):a>1)(x,i))?[]:g([...a,i]):g(a):b=a)(i=[],x++).length-k?F(n):[b,...F(n-1)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBCsIwEEX33kOZoWmwigiBSRaClwhZTGqtsTURK5Lb17iUbj6Px@Pf@cNT@wrPdx3TpZuvNMMgMm2R9Jki6WigJyadtQ7mN1W1aQzLKT06yKThRMDCl9ybE3jBa4@KdYOQRUA01qkerJSSRXBYmFF5YoRA1olcVSjHLvbvWz2YM0RU1otSF6wbdMq6uU1xSmMnx9TDFcrxAXH1L3cIx4XcIzTbhT0gFDl/AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
( k,                        // outer function taking k
  x = 0                     // x = bit mask of integers to include in the tuple
) =>                        // 
F = n =>                    // F = recursive function taking n
n ?                         // if n is not equal to 0:
  ( g = a =>                //   g is a recursive function taking a[]:
      x >> i ?              //     if x is greater than or equal to 2**i:
        x >> i++ & 1 ?      //       if the i-th bit is set in x:
          a.some(x =>       //         for each value x in a[]:
            ( C = (a, b) => //           C tests whether a and b are coprime:
              b ?           //             if b is not equal to 0:
                C(b, a % b) //               recursive call with (b, a mod b)
              :             //             else:
                a > 1       //               true if *not* coprime
            )(x, i)         //           initial call to C with (x, i)
          ) ?               //         end of some(); if truthy:
            []              //           abort by returning an empty array
          :                 //         else:
            g([...a, i])    //           append i to a[] and call g again
        :                   //       else:
          g(a)              //         just call g with a[] unchanged
      :                     //     else:
        b = a               //       done: return a[] and save it in b[]
  )(i = [], x++)            //   initial call to g with a = [], i = 0; increment x
  .length - k ?             //   if the length of the result is not equal to k:
    F(n)                    //     just call F with n unchanged
  :                         //   else:
    [b, ...F(n - 1)]        //     append b[] to the final result and decrement n
:                           // else:
  []                        //   stop recursion
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 58 bytes

```
ＮθＮη≔⁰ζ⊞υ⟦⟧Ｗ‹ＬΦυ⁼Ｌκθη«≦⊕ζＦΦυ⬤κ⬤…²ζ∨﹪μξ﹪ζξ⊞υ⁺⟦ζ⟧κ»Ｉ…Φυ⁼Ｌιθη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY5NT8MwDIbP66/w0ZGCNMZxp2kCaRJjFddph9CFJqqbtPngo4jfXrx1oF3w4bUey379VkaFyisax43rcnrK7YsO2Itlcc2GeRWjrR3OJQxMZY4Gs4T9geHdWNKAjzpGFlcngw@WEh/yxn2fFf3NGyGhF4LVCAFfxWyruovzxlVBt9olfZx@zF59gCunFRE2U3tWrta4OO1J2AXc@mMmj62EDx5caDjRueA3bkk54n44SGgEf/guymBdwrWKLJ8V6bXx3b/h7RT@nF0sx/EObufjzRv9AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `k` and `n`.

```
≔⁰ζ⊞υ⟦⟧
```

Start the master list with a 0-tuple whose largest number is 0.

```
Ｗ‹ＬΦυ⁼Ｌκθη«
```

Repeat until we have at least `k` `n`-tuples.

```
≦⊕ζ
```

Increment the candidate number.

```
ＦΦυ⬤κ⬤…²ζ∨﹪μξ﹪ζξ
```

Filter out all of the existing tuples where at least one member has a common factor with the candidate.

```
⊞υ⁺⟦ζ⟧κ
```

Prepend the candidate to each remaining tuple and push all the resulting tuples back to the master list.

```
»Ｉ…Φυ⁼Ｌιθη
```

Print the first `n` `k`-tuples.